# How to execute HQL file in pyspark using Hive warehouse connector

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hiveql

I have an hql file. I want to run it using pyspark with Hive warehouse connector. There is an executeQuery method to run queries. I want to know whether hql files can be run like that. Can we run complex queries like that.
Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Did below solution work or have you checked

Answer (score 1):

I have following solution where i have assumed that there will be multiple queries in hql file.

HQL File : sample_query.hql

```
select * from schema.table;
select * from schema.table2;
```

Code : Iterate over each query. You can do as you wish(in terms of HWC operation) in each iteration.

```
with open('sample_query.hql', 'r') as file:
    hql_file = file.read().rstrip()
    
for query in [x.lstrip().rstrip() for x in hql_file.split(";") if len(x) != 0] :
    hive.executeQuery("{0}".format(query))
```